# Merge two QuerySets or reorder one QS such that every n-th element will be from the second one

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-orm

I'm not sure if this can be done using only `Django` `ORM` or pure `SQL`. I have a model `Fruit` and I want to render a list of fruits such that every and only n-th fruit is of `type="apple"`.

So for 4 it would be:

- any fruit except apple
- any fruit except apple
- any fruit except apple
- apple
- any fruit except apple
- any fruit except apple
  ...

I'm looking for a more efficient way to do that than having a huge list of fruits, preferably one `QuerySet` but not sure if it's even possible.

```
fruits_except_apples = Fruit.objects.exclude(type='apple')
apples = Fruit.objects.filter(type='apple')
```

I can even create two `QuerySets` and then merge them somehow or just reorder one `QuerySet`.

Comment: Please add samples and expected output

Comment: @S-Man You can see the expected output - it's a list after "So for 4 it would be:"

Comment: Ok, but what is your input? I am sure there's a way with pure postgres but for that I need to now how it looks exactly :)

Comment: Input is just DB. Fruit.objects.all() for example. But I want Fruits of type='apple' to be only 4th,8th,12th,16th... etc

Comment: What do you mean by "a more efficient way to do that than having a huge list of fruits"? Regardless of the order, all the fruits will have to fetched from the database, right? Or are you talking about implementing some kind of pagination?

Comment: Yes, I use pagination too (infinite scroll but it's like pagination). I want to do a ModelManager method, something like: objecs.all_fruits_where_every_xth_is_apple(x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it helps but this query orders the fruits in your way. But I believe this could be done in a loop (SQL function or python) in a more efficient way.

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3c894cded42700ca1107fd63c7960faf)

```
SELECT 
    name, type
FROM (
    SELECT 
        name, type, 
        row_number + (row_number - 1) / 3 as row_number
    FROM (
        SELECT 
           *,
           row_number() OVER ()
        FROM fruits
        WHERE type != 'apple'
    )s

    UNION

    SELECT
        *,
        4 * row_number() OVER ()
    FROM fruits
    WHERE type = 'apple'
) s
ORDER BY row_number
```

**Step by step explanation:**

The main problem is to get an order with two different row counts: one in steps with 4 (4, 8, 12, ...) and one in steps with 1 but without the 4 steps (1,2,3,5,6,7,9,...), which is the real problem.

---

**My table**:

```
| name |      type |
|------|-----------|
|   A1 |     apple |
|   A2 |     apple |
|   A3 |     apple |
|   B1 |    banana |
|   B2 |    banana |
|   B3 |    banana |
|   B4 |    banana |
|   O1 |    orange |
|   K1 |      kiwi |
|   K2 |      kiwi |
|   K3 |      kiwi |
|   C1 | chocolate |
|   C2 | chocolate |
```

---

**First part. Get the orders of non-apples:**

Using the [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) `row_number`. This adds a row count column the data:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    row_number() OVER ()
FROM fruits
WHERE type != 'apple'

name  type       row_number  
----  ---------  ----------  
B1    banana     1           
B2    banana     2           
B3    banana     3           
B4    banana     4           
O1    orange     5           
K1    kiwi       6           
K2    kiwi       7           
K3    kiwi       8           
C1    chocolate  9           
C2    chocolate  10
```

Now we have to create the gaps. For that it is necessary to move blocks of 3: ids 4,5,6 should become 5,6,7; ids 7,8,9 should become 9,10,11 and so on.

The blocks of 3 can be achieved with an integer division of the `row_number` within the next subselect:

```
SELECT 
     *, 
     row_number / 3
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        row_number() OVER ()
    FROM fruits
    WHERE type != 'apple'
)s
```

which gives

```
name  type       row_number  ?column?  
----  ---------  ----------  --------  
B1    banana     1           0         
B2    banana     2           0         
B3    banana     3           1         
B4    banana     4           1         
O1    orange     5           1         
K1    kiwi       6           2         
K2    kiwi       7           2         
K3    kiwi       8           2         
C1    chocolate  9           3         
C2    chocolate  10          3
```

We can see that the simple division is still shifted. So with subtract 1 we get the result we are expecting:

```
SELECT 
     *, 
     (row_number - 1) / 3
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        row_number() OVER ()
    FROM fruits
    WHERE type != 'apple'
)s
```

which gives

```
name  type       row_number  ?column?  
----  ---------  ----------  --------  
B1    banana     1           0         
B2    banana     2           0         
B3    banana     3           0         
B4    banana     4           1         
O1    orange     5           1         
K1    kiwi       6           1         
K2    kiwi       7           2         
K3    kiwi       8           2         
C1    chocolate  9           2         
C2    chocolate  10          3
```

Now we can see that we can add the two rightmost columns to achieve our result:

```
SELECT 
     *, 
     (row_number - 1) / 3 + row_number
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        row_number() OVER ()
    FROM fruits
    WHERE type != 'apple'
)s
```

which gives

```
name  type       row_number  ?column?  
----  ---------  ----------  --------  
B1    banana     1           1         
B2    banana     2           2         
B3    banana     3           3         
B4    banana     4           5         
O1    orange     5           6         
K1    kiwi       6           7         
K2    kiwi       7           9         
K3    kiwi       8           10        
C1    chocolate  9           11        
C2    chocolate  10          13
```

---

To get the `apple` ids we simply use the `row_number()` function again which enumerates the `apple` rows with (1,2,3,...). Then we simply multiply these ids with 4 to get (4,8,12,...).

Both parts can be joined by an `UNION` and then has to be ordered by their generated ids.

Comment: Nice try. I'd like to see if it's possible to convert to Django ORM. Upvote

Comment: S-Man thanks, it works. @Satevg we are trying to convert it :)